# How to use one nic for storage traffic & other for network traffic?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, slackware, san

I have a Slackware Linux machine with two network interface cards and I want to use one interface for network traffic and other for storage traffic.

As this is Slackware, I don't know if this could be the solution or not but I am trying this:

```
ip route add IP1 dev eth0
ip route add IP2 dev eth1
```

**A diagram for reference**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bshfx.png]

Will this work or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 2):

In that case, routing is good enough as solution.

```
ip route add IP1 dev eth0
```

if IP1 belongs(assigned) to eth0 then you used command in wrong manner. You have to say to *ip route* **which** network(or host) you wish to route. If *SSIP* is San Storage IP then it should looks like:

```
ip route add SSIP via GatewayIP dev eth1
```

or in case Storage and Client are in same network segment

```
ip route add SSIP dev eth1
```

Also it can be used in form adding network

```
ip route add SS_Network/24 via GatewayIP dev eth1
```

Adding *one* route to Storage should be enough in most cases, you just explicitly give an order to route that or another network, trough that or another interface